# Error 404 en mern stack

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Estoy intentando crear un login en el mern stack pero estoy teniendo muchos problemas, el primero es que al momento de ejecutar toda mi api en el localhost me da un error si trato de hacer una solicitud post ya que me tira un error 404 en las rutas de la api, pero lo raro es que antes de eso no tengo ningún error todo me va correctamente.

aquí esta la parte lógica del componente LOGIN en el frontend

```
let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
            navigate('/login');

        }
    }, [navigate]);

    const loginHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const config = {
            header: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }

        try {
            const { data } = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', { email, password }, config)

            localStorage.setItem('authToken', data.token);

            navigate('/');
        } catch (error) {
            setError(error.response);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setError('');
            }, 5000)
        }
    }
```

Y aquí está la lógica de la ruta del backend

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if (!email || !password) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse('Por favor ingrese su correo y su contraseña', 400));
    }

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');

        if (!user) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse('Credenciales invalidas', 401));
        }

        const isMatch = await user.matchPasswords(password);

        if (!isMatch) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse('Contraseña invalida', 401));
        }

        sendToken(user, 200, res);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }
}
```

por ultima parte aquí esta las rutas del backend

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { register, login, forgotpassword, resetpassword } = require('../controllers/auth')

router.route('/register').post(register);
router.route('/login').post(login);
router.route('/forgotpassword').post(forgotpassword);
router.route('/resetpassword/:resetToken').put(resetpassword);


module.exports = router;
```

y la ruta privada:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { getPrivateData } = require('../controllers/private');
const { protect } = require('../middleware/auth');

router.route('/').get(protect, getPrivateData);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Si bota 404 lo mas probable es que estés definiendo mal la ruta... donde defines la ruta? (ese código no lo incluiste)

Comment: Hola pipe, el problema no va en la ruta te lo puedo asegurar, ya que antes de realizar cualquier solicitud en axios va bien, puedo ocupar links y todo pero cuando realizo un llamado al backend, pero si sirve de algo aqui esta `const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { register, login, forgotpassword, resetpassword } = require('../controllers/auth')

router.route('/register').post(register);
router.route('/login').post(login);
router.route('/forgotpassword').post(forgotpassword);
router.route('/resetpassword/:resetToken').put(resetpassword);
`

Comment: Mejor edita tu pregunta para incluir el código nuevo, porque aquí en los comentarios es ilegible. Y así por encima, no veo en donde defines que las rutas vayan precedidas por `/api/auth`, donde estás definiendo eso? incluye eso en tu pregunta tambien.

Comment: ok ahorita la edito

Comment: Sigo sin ver en donde estan las rutas precedidas por `/api/auth`...